# Return value from tracking script

Tags: javascript, key

I have the below tracking script loading on my site. I want to return "checkout_date" value for GTM purposes. Function will be run through GTM.

Once i have the correct return fucntion js i can implement. I've tried a few things found here but all of them seem to require "var name =" which i don't see present anywhere.

For example, i have tried the below with no success:

```
function (for(checkout_date in window.hTaxis.criteoBasketTag)) {
    if(window.hTaxis.criteoBasketTag.hasOwnProperty(checkout_date)) {
        return "checkout_date" = data[checkout_date];
        //do something with value;
    }
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.hTaxis = window.hTaxis || {};
    window.criteo_q = window.criteo_q || [];

    window.criteo_q.push(
        { event: "setAccount", account: 31165 },
        { event: "setSiteType", type: window.hTaxis.siteType },
        { event: "setHashedEmail", email: "" },
        { event: "viewItem", item: 1016454 },
        {
            event: "viewSearch",
            checkin_date: "2020-01-31",
            checkout_date: "2020-02-07"
        }
    );

    window.hTaxis.criteoBasketTag = [
        {event: "setAccount", account: 31165},
        {event: "setSiteType", type: window.hTaxis.siteType},
        {event: "setHashedEmail", email: ""},
        {
            event: "viewBasket", item: [
                {
                    id: 1016454,
                    price: 39.64,
                    quantity: 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            event: "viewSearch",
            checkin_date: "2020-01-31",
            checkout_date: "2020-02-07"
        }
    ];
</script>
```

Comment: Im seeing a data structure but not any code. Where is your *own* attempt to solve your problem?

Comment: Presumably you have some server-side code that generates this Javascript data structure. Can't that code also save the checkout_date value somewhere where it could be picked up by GTM…? It's a bit unclear how the different pieces are supposed to interact here.

Comment: I have tried using:
```
function (for(checkout_date in window.hTaxis.criteoBasketTag)) {
    if(window.hTaxis.criteoBasketTag.hasOwnProperty(checkout_date)) {
        return "checkout_date" = data[checkout_date];
        //do something with value;
    }
}
```
A tthe moment I do not have access to development to populate this value else to be picked up by GTM

Comment: Additional info: this js is loaded post CSS pre <head>

Comment: what is your understanding of GTM? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTM What do you mean by "loaded  pre <head>"? you cannot have script prior to the `<head></head>` and if you do, browsers will do unpredictable things to that invalid markup.

Comment: That being said, I think you want something like `function getThing(mythingArray, thingName) {
  for (let i = 0; i < mythingArray.length; i++) {
    item = mythingArray[i];
    if (item.hasOwnProperty(thingName)) {
      return item[thingName];
    }
  }
}
var datething = getThing(window.hTaxis.criteoBasketTag, "checkout_date");
alert(datething);`

Comment: What is GTM? Is this an appt reuniting: "A go-to-market strategy (GTM strategy) is an action plan that specifies how a company will reach target customers and achieve competitive advantage."

Comment: Please `edit ` your answer to include pertinent information, rather than just adding it as comments. All info necessary to solve and understand the Dustin must be embedded in the body of the question itself.

Comment: Please also correct capitalization, grammar, and typos, as indicated in StackOverflow posting guidelines [How to Ask](https://StackOverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It makes posts easier to read, saves every person from needing to mentally correct and process the post, and volunteers are more likely to choose to spend *their* time on questions where the OP has clearly spent time and effort creating clear, well-formed questions. It also shows respect, attending to detail (necessary to coding), and is an indication that the OP put due diligence in while debugging their own issue before asking.